# Authorize SonarQube api

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am trying to use an Api to get the value of some metrics with a c# application. My code looks like this:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myServer/api/measures/component?componentKey=myProject&metricKeys=bugs,new_bugs");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
try
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string result;
    using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var joResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
    var measures = (JArray)joResponse["component"]["measures"];

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

When i write the same API into the address box of my browser, i get the result i looked for. And the token for the header is generated by my server. But for some reason I catch an error 401 when trying to get the response for this httpwebrequest in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Alternatively, instead of using a token, I tried using credentials:

```
httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(name, password);
```

The result was the same.

EDIT:

I tried to use the header

`httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

instead. This also didn't work out.

Comment: Did you try `httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);` (with Bearer)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem last week and couldn't believe what I've experienced.
In the "Authorization" header you have to encode the token with an empty password like this:

```
"Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKey + ":"))}"
```

The colon after "apiKey" is very important.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thanks! I used your clue like this: `new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token + ":")));` where the `token` is set to the token copied from SQ.